# Sorting a string to make a new one

Tags: python, string, python-2.7, sorting, nested-loops

Here I had to remove the most frequent alphabet of a string(if frequency of two alphabets is same, then in alphabetical order) and put it into new string.

Input:

```
abbcccdddd
```

Output:

```
dcdbcdabcd
```

The code I wrote is:

```
s = list(sorted(<the input string>))
a = []
for c in range(len(s)):
    freq =[0 for _ in range(26)]
    for x in s:
        freq[ord(x)-ord('a')] += 1
    m = max(freq)
    allindices = [p for p,q in enumerate(freq) if q == m]
    r = chr(97+allindices[0])
    a.append(r)
    s.remove(r)
print''.join(a)
```

But it passed the allowed runtime limit maybe due to too many loops.(There's another for loop which seperates the strings from user input)

I was hoping if someone could suggest a more optimised version of it using less memory space.

Comment: For the record, `list(sorted(...))` is redundant; `sorted` already returns a new `list`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your solution involves 26 linear scans of the string and a bunch of unnecessary 
conversions to count the frequencies. You can save some work by replacing all those linear scans with a linear count step, another linear repetition generation, then a sort to order your letters and a final linear pass to strip counts:

```
from collections import Counter      # For unsorted input
from itertools import groupby        # For already sorted input
from operator import itemgetter

def makenewstring(inp):
    # When inp not guaranteed to be sorted:
    counts = Counter(inp).iteritems()

    # Alternative if inp is guaranteed to be sorted:
    counts = ((let, len(list(g))) for let, g in groupby(inp))

    # Create appropriate number of repetitions of each letter tagged with a count
    # and sort to put each repetition of a letter in correct order
    # Use negative n's so much more common letters appear repeatedly at start, not end
    repeats = sorted((n, let) for let, cnt in counts for n in range(0, -cnt, -1))

    # Remove counts and join letters
    return ''.join(map(itemgetter(1), repeats))
```

---

**Updated:** It occurred to me that my original solution could be made much more concise, a one-liner actually (excluding required imports), that minimizes temporaries, in favor of a single sort-by-key operation that uses a trick to sort each letter by the count of that letter seen so far:

```
from collections import defaultdict
from itertools import count

def makenewstring(inp):
    return ''.join(sorted(inp, key=lambda c, d=defaultdict(count): (-next(d[c]), c)))
```

This is actually the same basic logic as the original answer, it just accomplishes it by having `sorted` perform the decoration and undecoration of the values implicitly instead of doing it ourselves explicitly (implicit decorate/undecorate is the whole point of `sorted`'s `key` argument; it's doing the [Schwartzian transform](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schwartzian_transform) for you).

Performance-wise, both approaches are similar; they both (in practice) scale linearly for smaller inputs (the one-liner up to inputs around 150 characters long, the longer code, using `Counter`, up to inputs in the `len` 2000 range), and while the growth is super-linear above that point, it's always below the theoretical `O(n log_2 n)` (likely due to the data being not entirely random thanks to the counts and limited alphabet, ensuring Python's TimSort has some existing ordering to take advantage of). The one-liner is somewhat faster for smaller strings (`len` 100 or less), the longer code is somewhat faster for larger strings (I'm guessing it has something to do with the longer code creating some ordering by grouping runs of counts for each letter). Really though, it hardly matters unless the input strings are expected to be huge.

Comment: This is an interesting solution. If every letter has a very large frequency then this would have to create a list based on the huge frequencies and sort it. Which makes max run time to O N log N where N is the frequencies.

Comment: However i think Timsort might make this efficient regardless of that, im not 100% sure though

Comment: @jamylak: Ah, yeah, I had a slight variant on this solution that had them ordered in reverse, forgot to fix that part when I tweaked it. I think the runtime is `O(n log n)` where `n` is the total length of the string, which isn't ideal (I don't think TimSort will help much here because the elements aren't particularly ordered), though the C level sorting tends to run fairly fast.

Comment: @jamylak: FYI, I decided to test the scaling. On my Python 3.5 install, up through moderate length strings (a few hundred random characters for the new one-liner solution, a few thousand for the original solution using `Counter`, with limited alphabet, e.g. lowercase ASCII, unsorted), the scaling factor is actually sub-linear. It eventually goes super-linear, but thanks to TimSort's ability to exploit partial ordering, it stays meaningfully below `O(n log n)` all the way up through strings with ridiculous (>1M) lengths (the multiline solution takes ~8800x longer for `128*8192` than for `128`).

Comment: Feel free to link me the test if you havent deleted it by now

Answer (score 1):

Since the alphabet will always be a constant 26 characters,
this will work in O(N) and only takes a constant amount of space of 26

```
from collections import Counter
from string import ascii_lowercase

def sorted_alphabet(text):
    freq = Counter(text)
    alphabet = filter(freq.get, ascii_lowercase) # alphabet filtered with freq >= 1
    top_freq = max(freq.values()) if text else 0 # handle empty text eg. ''
    for top_freq in range(top_freq, 0, -1): # from top_freq to 1
        for letter in alphabet:
            if freq[letter] >= top_freq:
                yield letter

print ''.join(sorted_alphabet('abbcccdddd'))
print ''.join(sorted_alphabet('dbdd'))
print ''.join(sorted_alphabet(''))
print ''.join(sorted_alphabet('xxxxaaax'))
```

---

```
dcdbcdabcd
ddbd

xxaxaxax
```

Answer (score 0):

What about this?
I am making use of in-built python functions to eliminate loops and improve efficiency.

```
test_str = 'abbcccdddd'

remaining_letters = [1]   # dummy initialisation
# sort alphabetically
unique_letters = sorted(set(test_str))
frequencies = [test_str.count(letter) for letter in unique_letters]

out = []

while(remaining_letters):

    # in case of ties, index takes the first occurence, so the alphabetical order is preserved  
    max_idx = frequencies.index(max(frequencies))    
    out.append(unique_letters[max_idx])

    #directly update frequencies instead of calculating them again
    frequencies[max_idx] -= 1  
    remaining_letters = [idx for idx, freq in enumerate(frequencies) if freq>0]

print''.join(out)   #dcdbcdabcd
```